# Track Order page, having issues with footer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page where users can track the status of an order, I've created a demo order just for this issue: [Click Here](https://www.macmetro.com/track-sale-order/YI9RJGCZDA)

If someone who is viewing the status decides to click on FAQs, Terms or our Contact page, it adds the /track-sale-order/ to those links, instead of it showing /faqs, it will show /track-sale-order/faqs which is a problem. This issue does not occur on any other pages.

Here is the code for the footer links:

```html
<a class="footer-links" href="faqs">FAQs</a> | <a href="terms" class="footer-links">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="contact" class="footer-links">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: Show footer view code. Probably you are using relative url on anchor instead `base_url('faq')`. I.e. `<a href="faq">FAQ</a>` instead `<a href="<?php echo base_url('faq'); ?>">FAQ</a>` or `<a href="/faq">FAQ</a>`. If you prepend forward slash it will check link relative to root. Advice is using `base_url()` with parameter tho.

Comment: Added code, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using relative url on anchor instead `base_url('faqs')`. I.e. `<a href="faqs">FAQ</a>` instead `<a href="<?php echo base_url('faqs'); ?>">FAQ</a>` or `<a href="/faq">FAQ</a>`. If you prepend forward slash it will check link relative to root. Advice is using `base_url()` with parameter tho.

Switch `href="faqs"` for `href="<?php echo base_url('faqs'); ?>"`. And do that for other links too.

```
<a class="footer-links" href="<?php echo base_url('faqs'); ?>">FAQs</a> | <a href="<?php echo base_url('terms'); ?>" class="footer-links">Terms of Service</a> | <a href="<?php echo base_url('contact'); ?>" class="footer-links">Contact Us</a>
```

Comment: @FrankZwan Accept answer if so and others with same issue can use solution too.